# What does this checkmark icon next to Roblox usernames mean?

Tags: roblox

I saw someone with this checkmark (✔️) symbol next to their username and I am curious about what it means.

Comment: Can you please provide an image to go with the post? Thanks!

Comment: @Henry Bass See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384371. (Same question by another user, but it does have an attached image). I provided a partial answer, suggest closing this as a duplicate once a good answer is provided there.