# What does this bag with a checkmark on it next to Roblox usernames mean?

Tags: roblox

This is really confusing me. Please, can someone tell me what this means?
Notice how to the left of some of these usernames is a checkmark symbol.

[image: List of usernames, some of which have a shopping bag with checkmark next to them]

Comment: I have been wondering that too

Answer (score 15):

The icon means the user was *verified* by the roblox system.

Some popular users have had trouble with imposters using their display name (since it does not have to be unique), or a lookalike username to scam others. The checkmark allows others to see that the account is more likely genuine as there are some requirements attached before you can get one.

I have not yet found what these requirements are, or how the process of getting this icon next to a username works. It might be associated with an in-app purchase (as it's likely such users can be trusted, for they have something to lose if their account is banned).

Comment: Thank you I jsut always see these in bloxburg